# Can lug nuts be tightened with a powered non-impact driver plus torque wrench?

Tags: wheels, tools, lug-nut

I understand that lug nuts should not be tightened with an impact wrench because of the risk of over-torquing. Could a lug nut be tightened most of the way with a powered non-impact driver and then finished off with a torque wrench?

Specifically, is this a reasonable and/or common approach, and are there any caveats?

Comment: The only "powered" drivers I've ever scene for this type of operation is an impact driver. Can you please let me know exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: My understanding is that a typical cordless driver/drill is not an impact driver, but I acknowledge that I could be totally confused. For example, https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00ET5VMTU/

Comment: A "typical cordless driver/drill" would not be used for this operation. They don't develop enough torque to do the job. Only an impact driver would have enough force to break a lug free. There are cordless impacts which can be used. In fact, Dewalt makes a [1/2" drive impact](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-20-Volt-Max-XR-Lithium-Ion-1-2-in-Cordless-Impact-Wrench-Kit-with-Detent-Pin-Anvil-Tool-Only-DCF899B/206159781?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-BASE-PLA-D25T-PowerTools%7c&gclid=COjG1eHbx9ACFUtXDQodXbsMRQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) which can produce up to 700 lb-ft of torque.

Comment: @Paulster2, I know that an ordinary cordless driver is inappropriate for loosening a lug nut, but I'm asking about tightening it.

Comment: You've asked if it is a "reasonable and/or common approach" ... the answer to this is no. Doesn't mean you cannot use one. It just means most mechanics (even back yard mechanics) wouldn't.

Comment: I've use a cordless drill before to tighten lug nuts before torqueing.  Not sure how much of an advantage it was, but seemed to go quicker and a little easier.

Answer (score 4):

tl dr: No. Not a driver/drill as you've described.

Usually, hand tools are used for the tightening of lugs, then followed with a torque wrench to ensure accuracy in getting the wheels onto a vehicle. This is not only the preferred method, but how it should be done.

There is one caveat ... if you use torque sticks, you can use an impact gun. A torque stick is a device which, when the lug gets to the specific torque needed, will give enough to not tighten any more. They are magic, but work perfectly. You'll see tire shops use these because it saves a lot of time.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a link to the [Torque-Stick site](http://www.torquestick.com/cart/). I'm only including it for reference to what I'm talking about.

Comment: Everything I've seen online says to tighten by hand--I haven't seen any mention of using non-impact drivers.

Comment: @amcnabb - Did you mean to say "impact" and not "non-impact" drivers? I've updated the question with the product mentioned.

Comment: I think amcnabb means "by hand" as opposed to a non-impact "powered driver". The OP mentions use of a "non-impact driver", which could be either hand tools only or a powered driver without an impact feature... so, the question would be: **Is it OK to use a non-impact powered driver then finish up with a torque wrench, or should this job be completed using hand-powered tools only?"**

Comment: I have not seen any shop in our area not follow up the torque stick with a torque wrench for final set.

Comment: @Paulster2, yes, that is what I meant. I'll edit my question accordingly to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @amcnabb - I've updated for a second time, in light of how you changed the question.

Comment: @Paulster2, I disagree with your answer because the OP said nothing about removing lug nuts, it was specific to tightening. I don't see any reason why one could not use a cordless (or corded) driver to initially tighten the lug nuts *most of the way* (no significant torque needed just to chase em on), then follow up with a torque wrench for the final set.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - You'd never see it happen in a shop. I guess it doesn't mean you couldn't do it at home, but that's not what a drill is for and usually wouldn't be used for it.

Comment: I've never seen a torque wrench in any tire change place in my country or even at most of the mechanics shops I've been to. However one tire change place had an air driven impact wrench which they said had some kind of torque clutch on it that they set to a low setting so as not to damage anything.

Comment: @Paulster2, I would love to see an explanation for why it's a bad idea. Is it just that the torque stick approach is significantly better? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @amcnabb - The torque stick prevents over tightening. If you put lugs on with an impact, you can easily over tighten them. Then you'd never know it even if you checked it with a torque wrench, because the torque wrench would click (or register) the lug had already hit the torque spec, but wouldn't tell you the lug has already gone past that point. By using a torque stick, there's no way to over tighten because the stick will not allow it to happen.